# cmocka free operation and catching exceptions

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing, cmocka

I started my adventure with [cmocka](https://api.cmocka.org/) library, and I have two questions.

1. Is it possible to find out if free() operation was made correctly? I mean, I would like to test function which is cleaning up tree structure. I've read about test_free(), but honestly I don't understand idea behind that.
2. The second thing is case of catching standard library exceptions. I know about function `expect_assert_failure`, but how to use it? For example I would to do something what will throw segmentation fault, but I would like to pass test anyway.

Comment: For testing free, if you won't use the `test_free()` provided with cmocka (assuming that's where it comes from), then consider using [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) instead.  There are no exceptions in standard C -- not in the sense that C++ or Java means exceptions.  An `expect_assert_failure()` function might be part of cmocka library; you'll need to read the manual on what it does and is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest just doing an additonal test with valgrind.

```
valgrind --error-exitcode=1 ./test
```

Without the option valgrind would always return the same exit code returned by your test program. This way if your test program succeeds, but valgrind's memory check reveals errors, it will return 1 to indicate an error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
#define UNIT_TESTING 1
```

before you include the `cmocka.h` header file, then `malloc`, `realloc` and free get overridden and will warn you about memory leaks.

`expect_assert_failure()` if for checking that an `assert()` condition is really hit.